# passphrase issue with correct ssh keys

Tags: ssh, encryption, git

It is the first time I experienced this issue : I have setup `ssh` keys and I set the passphrase. Since the file is not `id_rsa` but `id_rsd`, I set this

```
Host someIP
  HostName someIP
  User git
  IdentityFile /Users/mehdibenchoufi/.ssh/id_rsd.pub
```

Now, when I connect via `ssh -vT someIP`, I am asked to enter the passsphrase. I did it correctly, but the passphrase does not seem to be recognized. How can it be ? (btw, I changed the  perms on `id_rsd*` setting it to 700 since Gitlab's server on which I am trying to clone from complained about the 640 default perms)

Comment: Shouldn't that be the private key file, rather than the public one?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify private key for `IdentityFile` option, as described in manual page for [`ssh_config(5)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man5/ssh_config.5.html):

```
IdentityFile /Users/mehdibenchoufi/.ssh/id_rsd
```

If `ssh` does not recognize the key typ, it tries to decrypt it regardless the content of the file, which ends in nonsense (regardless the passphrase).